# Paypal sandbox login error : Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again

Tags: paypal

I can't login to Paypal sandbox and not sure what I'm doing wrong. How can I get past this?

1) Visit https://developer.paypal.com and login -- I am able to do this successfully using my existing Paypal account credentials.

2) Click Sandbox > Accounts which links to this URL https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

3) Click the link "Login with Paypal" which links to Paypal login screen with email / password and blue log in button.

Apparently I am supposed to re-enter my credentials here to login. But I keep getting the error "Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again."

4) I then try to visit my website and use credentials listed on sandbox developer page but get the same error "Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again."

Answer (score 12):

Even after creating an account, sandbox-acc i was still getting the same problem. 
I noticed that when you create an account from the [sandbox-dashboard](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)

You end up with two accounts. 1. support-facilitator, 2. buyer-facilitator

What you do is, when your check-out integration is ready, and you want to 'check-out'

Use the buyer-facilitator account to login in and make payments.

Note:

The 'env' variable in your integration should be set to 'sandbox'
Edit the password for the 'buyer-facilitator' [under > sandbox->[account]](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)
Use your new password to log-in and make a payment.

> The test account comes pre-loaded with 'funds' to facilitate transactions in the sandbox environment.

Comment: Nowadays there are two accounts in your sandbox  accounts -> `business` and `personal`. Login in for a test payment with the `personal` account worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you are still experiencing the same issue
Login into your developer account
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

1. Get to the "**Sandbox Accounts**"
2. Select one of the accounts -"View/Edit Accounts"
3. Under Profile use the **Email ID** and **System
   Generated Password** Provided
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8BAw.png)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was making is trying to login at https://www.paypal.com/ with my sandbox credentials. Instead, I needed to use https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/

Answer (score -1):

Create a sandbox account.
Or change your paypal app mode to Live